# How to display form errors in Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I wish to understand how to display errors that come from forms. For now, when I validate any form on my project, I don't have anything appearing.

How to display form errors in Symfony ?

Thank you for your help.

You can see my code from :

- **register.html.twig** file where my userform helping users to register is shown.
- **UserController.php** file where you can see what happens when userform is validated.
- Also **User.php** and **UserType.php**.

**register.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Incris-toi !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(userform) }}

    <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">

        {% set formErrors = userform.vars.errors.form.getErrors(true) %}

    {% if formErrors|length %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
            {% if userform.vars.value.email == null or userform.vars.value.email != 'email' or userform.vars.value.email != 'unique' %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.email) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.password|length < 6 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.password) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.gender == null or (userform.vars.value.gender != 'male' and userform.vars.value.gender != 'female' and userform.vars.value.gender != 'non-binary') %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.gender) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.firstname|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.firstname) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.lastname|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.lastname) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.birthdate == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.birthdate) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.occupation|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.occupation) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.nationality == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.nationality) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.nativelanguage == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.nativelanguage) }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    </div>
    
    {{ form_widget(userform.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.password) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.gender) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.firstname) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.lastname) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.birthdate) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.occupation) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.nationality) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.nativelanguage) }}
    {{ form_widget(userform.save) }}

{{ form_end(userform) }}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/register', name: 'register', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function createUser(
        Request $request,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface,
        UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface
    ){
        $user = new User();
        $userform = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userform->isSubmitted() && $userform->isValid()) {

            $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);

            $plainPassword = $userform->get('password')->getData();
            $hashedPassword = $userPasswordHasherInterface->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
            $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

            $entityManagerInterface->persist($user);
            $entityManagerInterface->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('front/register.html.twig', [
            'userform' => $userform,
        ]);
    }
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié d\'entrer ton adresse e-mail.')]
    #[Assert\Email(message: 'Entre une adresse e-mail valide.')]
    private ?string $email = null;

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de créer un mot de passe.')]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 6, minMessage: 'Crée un mot de passe de 6 caractères minimum.')]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de sélectionner ton genre.')]
    private ?string $gender = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié d\'entrer ton prénom.')]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, minMessage: 'Écris un prénom valide.')]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié d\'entrer ton nom de famille.')]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, minMessage: 'Écris un nom de famille valide.')]
    private ?string $lastname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de sélectionner ta date de naissance.')]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $birthdate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de nous dire ce que tu fais.')]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, minMessage: 'Écris une occupation valide.')]
    private ?string $occupation = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'users')]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de nous sélectionner le pays d\'où tu viens.')]
    private ?Country $nationality = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'users')]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Tu as oublié de nous sélectionner ta langue maternelle.')]
    private ?Language $nativelanguage = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->participations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getGender(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    public function setGender(string $gender): self
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function setBirthdate(?\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOccupation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->occupation;
    }

    public function setOccupation(string $occupation): self
    {
        $this->occupation = $occupation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNationality(): ?Country
    {
        return $this->nationality;
    }

    public function setNationality(?Country $nationality): self
    {
        $this->nationality = $nationality;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNativelanguage(): ?Language
    {
        return $this->nativelanguage;
    }

    public function setNativelanguage(?Language $nativelanguage): self
    {
        $this->nativelanguage = $nativelanguage;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**UserType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Country;
use App\Entity\Language;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je suis ...' => '',
                    'un homme' => 'male',
                    'une femme' =>'female',
                    'non-binaire' => 'non-binary'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
                ],
                'choice_translation_domain' => true
            ])
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('nationality', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Country::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis un pays'
            ])
            ->add('nativelanguage', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Je sélectionne ma langue maternelle'
            ])
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password']
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

-- This question is still open. --

EDIT : I have found the way to display error messages. But this problem persists : password doesn't show its error message. I don't understand why.

Comment: I added UserController.php so that you can see what happens with validation. Also, I wish to display only one error by the time, this is why I wanted to separate each error.

Comment: Thank you Marleen. I added ```User``` and ```UserType``` files.

Comment: "How to display form errors in Symfony ?" - what exactly is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for asking Nico Haase. Yes, I moved forward... I finally succeeded to have proper errors messages displayed. However, there is still something that doesn't work properly. I don't get an error message when the password is not filled in. I think it comes from twig file. I don't understand why. I am going to update my description with it.

Comment: "I don't get an error message when the password is not filled in", Don't use the attribute password in the formType but create another  attribute plainPassword , the example is here https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine/registration_form.html#create-a-form-for-the-entity

Comment: Thank you hous. I tried your solution but UserPasswordEncoderInterface class is not available.

Comment: I did ```{{ dump(formErrors) }}```in register.html.twig. I could find the error message related to the password. It just doesn't display.

Comment: From this example take just the idea how to add "plainPassword". For the rest of code hashing password and other, use the example in the doc of your symfony version, I think it's v 6

Comment: I use 6.2 Symfony version. The v 6 uses UserPasswordEncoderInterface, but it doesn't exist at v 6.2.

Comment: I also had a look to the page you sent to me, at version 6.2 this time. Sadly, they did not write a procedure for version 6.2...

Comment: Ok, Can you make a new question ? Or how can I send you an example of code ?

Comment: At the moment, I am not allowed to make a new question. Can you post a new answer ? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: In symfony 6 it's UserPasswordHasherInterface https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html

Comment: Yes hous. If you see my UserController.php in description it's exactly what I used. Tell me, is there something I need to change in my code ?

Comment: I don't know where the problem might be. Actually, I succeeded to have the other errors, but only when I remove them from the condition. Thank you for trying to help hous...

Comment: I have updated this response, you can find all codes, Entity, FormType, Controller, twig because I can't make new response because it will not be related to your main question subject.
this is the response link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74070121/3866856

Answer (score 4):

Try to test "firstname" for example with min length 3 by typing only 2 chars in the form, the form error appears or no ?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
#[Assert\Length(min: 3)]
private ?string $firstname = null;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message="Mot de passe ne doit pas être vide."
 * )
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min="6",
 *     max="32",
 *     minMessage="Mot de passe doit avoir au minimum ({{ limit }}) caractères.",
 *     maxMessage="Mot de passe doit avoir au maximum ({{ limit }}) caractères."
 * )
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

public function getPlainPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword(?string $password): self
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;

    return $this;
}
```

FormType:

```
        use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
        use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_options'  => array(
                'label' => 'Mot de passe (6 caractères au minimum)',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Mot de passe ne doit pas être vide',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Mot de passe doit avoir au minimum {{ limit }} caractères',
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],

            ),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe ne sont pas identiques'
        ))
```

The controller:

```
    use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

    private UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher)
{
    $this->passwordHasher = $passwordHasher;
}

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user->addRole('ROLE_AAAAAA');
        $user->setPassword(
            $this->passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()));

     // ...........
     }
```

Twig form:

```
  {% if not userform.vars.valid %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ form_errors(userform) }}
    {% for children in userform.children %}
        {% if not children.vars.valid %}
            {{ form_errors(children) }}
        {% endif %}
        {% for child in children %}
            {% if not child.vars.valid %}
                {{ form_errors(child) }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}


        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes hous, the form error appears.

Comment: good, try also to not using "error_bubbling => true', let it false by default because

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

Comment: Hello hous. Could you give me a hand ? I am trying to find the way to set errors messages when fields from form are not filled.

Comment: Hello, just add assert\notBlank and remove "error_bubbling => true', , it should work

Comment: Yes, I removed ```error_bubbling => true```. The problem remains the same.

Comment: What is the error you get ?
Just for test, remove this line " {{ form_errors(userform.birthdate) }}" and change form_widget by form_row " like this "{{ form_row(userform.birthdate) }}" and try again and tell me what you get

Comment: This interesting, because I get the error just under the field. I feel we are moving forward... Now, it would be better to have the error in the "alert-danger" div.

Comment: The errors should appears inside the div. Try to not put them inside any div to test if is it a css or javascript problem. Maybe they are hidden inside this div

Comment: So should I keep ```{{ form_errors(userform) }}```?

Comment: Yes keep the block of errors as is it and use form_widget this time not form_row. Don't put them inside this div alert to test css and js

Comment: Ok. I just tried but ```{{ form_errors(userform) }}```doesn't show any error.

Comment: Is it {{ form_errors(userform) }} or {{ form_errors(userform.birthday) }} ?

Comment: I used this time ```{{ form_errors(userform) }}```.

Comment: Now, I used ```{{ form_errors(userform.birthdate) }}``` and it worked !

Comment: I get every errors which is good !

Comment: Good. So the problem comes from div alert, try to fix css or js or maybe role=alert, I'm not sure about it but sure comes from this alert, it hides the content

Comment: @EmilieTossan ,  have a look of this response edits

Comment: Yes, I had a look. I did what you said. The form error doesn't appear for 'firstname' when I typed 2 characters.

Comment: But it does when I remove the error from the condition and I place it just outside.

Comment: My edits is about password not about firstname

Comment: It's the same thing with password.

Comment: It worked when I wrote ```{{ form_errors(userform.password.first) }}``` but I had the remove it from condition and paste it just outside the condition.

Comment: You can use " {% if not userform.vars.valid %}" , I have updated the response, in the end you find how to show errors in twig

Comment: I wish to display errors one by one, so I need to make condition for each error.

Comment: This condition ```{% elseif userform.vars.value.password == null %}``` doesn't work when ```userform.vars.value.password```is actually ```null```.

Comment: I will open a new ticket hous, don't worry. (I can open new ticket again, phew...)

Comment: It's not like this, not in twig you will test if field is null or not or is blank, in twig you will just show the error messages coming from Symfony validation (assert). In twig you can just count the number of errors and display them but not test validation.
{% if userform.plainPassword.first.vars.errors|length %}

Comment: Can you explain how you would show one error one after the other (not all of them at the same time) ?

Comment: Here is the new ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117160/how-can-i-show-form-error-one-after-the-other-condition-not-working

Comment: Form erros for each field is an array, a field can has one or more erros so you need to do a loop for. Sorry I'll see the ticket tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

_ I think there is a problem with your User class, you didn't set any validations for your form : https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#validating-forms

> Validation is done by adding a set of rules, called (validation) constraints, to a class. You can add them either to the entity class or to the form class.

Try to add some rules (#[Assert\NotBlank]) to your class and your form will throw errors if it's not fit.

_ Also, you need te remove your default value on your fields in your User class ( = null) to the variable you need to be filled (at least you need to remove the ID one, who can't be null).

_ In your form on each fields, you set 'error_bubbling' to true : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

> If true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.

If you want to have the control on every field, i think you need to remove this option, then symfony will attach errors on each fields.
Or you can let this option but then you need to update your code in the Alert div, to not render each fields, but the parent field or form.

Comment: Symfony [will guess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#validating-objects) _some_ validation constraints directly from the doctrine metadata. Although is not _strictly neccessary_ to add the constraints manually it's more explicit and it'll give you finer control, so it's not a bad practice, if you ask me.