# How can I show form error one after the other ? (Condition 'elseif' not working)

Tags: forms, symfony

I don't know how to show one form error one after the other when fields are empty : it worked for email, but not for password, gender, ect... I believe it comes from the condition I created because I get the proper error message when I remove them and paste them just outside the condition.

Where is be the mistake ?

**register.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(userform, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}} ) }}

    {% set formErrors = userform.vars.errors.form.getErrors(true) %}
    {{ dump(userform.vars.value.password|length) }}
    {% if formErrors|length %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
            {% if userform.vars.value.email == null or userform.vars.value.email != 'email' or userform.vars.value.email != 'unique' %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.email) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.password|length < 6 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.password.first) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.gender == null or (userform.vars.value.gender != 'male' and userform.vars.value.gender != 'female' and userform.vars.value.gender != 'non-binary') %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.gender) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.firstname|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.firstname) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.lastname|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.lastname) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.birthdate == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.birthdate) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.occupation|length < 2 %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.occupation) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.nationality == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.nationality) }}
            {% elseif userform.vars.value.nativelanguage == null %}
                {{ form_errors(userform.nativelanguage) }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: the mistake is in the wrong use of elseif. what you get is the expected behavior. read [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Hello gp_sflover. I used a twig file so I referred to this document : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{ form_errors(form) }} is not to do test if field is empty or not or is valid or not but just to display validations messages from Symfony Validator such Assert.

For exmple when you say:

```
{% if userform.vars.value.email == null %}
```

yes the first time when you comme on the url of form , the email is always null but this not how we test if email is blank, we don't test it in twig.

> Keep in mind that {{ form_errors(form) }} is just for **displaying** errors messages, just for **showing**

Let's take this example :

```
 class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
 {
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'Email ne doit pas être vide')]
    #[Assert\Email(message: 'Email n\'est pas valide')]
    private ?string $email;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 3, max: 32, minMessage: 'msg min ...', maxMessage: 'msg max ....')]
    private $plainPassword;
```

In User class we have already added a validation test if email is empty or is not valid usnig Assert.

The role of form_erros in twig is **just** **showing** this errors messages if they exists but **not** testing validation

So what you can do in twig is to test if form is valid or not, if not valid so display erros:

```
{% if not userform.vars.valid %}

   {{ form_errors(userform.email) }} // if email is empty or not valid, it will show the message of Assert in user class
   {{ form_errors(userform.firstName) }}
   {{ form_errors(userform.lastName) }}
   {{ form_errors(userform.plainPassword.first) }}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ok hous. I replaced ```{% if formErrors|length %} #}```with ```{% if not userform.vars.valid %}```. But the issue is that I'm looking to display one error at a time. When I use your solution, I have every errors displayed at the same time. It's not what I want...

Comment: you mean you want to test field by field ? if so , you can try like this `{% if not form.vars.valid %}

    {% if not userform.email.vars.valid %}
        {{ form_errors(userform.email) }}
    {% endif %}
    
{% endif %}`

Comment: Yes, that worked very well !